# Make SVG scale to full screen size - width and height

Tags: css, svg, aspect-ratio, codepen

I have a problem with my svg animation line.
I would like it to fill all the width and length of the screen like this website https://www.lemonade.com/giveback-2019 but for now it's very small only in a column the in the center.
I tried to change the Aspect Ratio but it just ruin the image. I also tried to change the width and the height but it goes out of the central column and then disappears.

This is my code:
https://codepen.io/codewithim/pen/KKREVPw

```
          <div class="linecont">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 2871 5851" fill="none" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet">
              <path d="M6.13024 0.179993C6.13024 0.179993 -5.93976 407.65 703.97 271.94C1413.87 136.23 2393.8 289.96 2554.29 374.76C2714.78 459.56 3224.73 1026.17 2375.85 1377.68C2375.85 1377.68 1684.78 1415.68 1548.28 1347.43C1548.28 1347.43 1428.6 1265.58 1525.95 1194.64C1525.95 1194.64 1558.95 1184.74 1589.47 1195.46C1619.99 1206.18 1611.44 1277.93 1585.35 1315.08C1559.25 1352.23 1448.8 1561.78 1448.8 1561.78L1421.52 1618.04C1421.52 1618.04 1450.94 1681.08 1466.07 1618.04C1466.07 1618.04 1377.04 1325.34 1258.06 1299.74C1258.06 1299.74 1206.16 1271.24 1126.9 1308.79C1126.9 1308.79 358.16 1882.7 232.06 1834.43C232.06 1834.43 123.27 1828.78 133.5 1730.38C143.73 1631.98 349.55 1673.12 313.92 1753.44C313.92 1753.44 317.75 1840.81 279.47 1901.13C279.47 1901.13 257.35 2043.32 496.97 2076.64C736.59 2109.96 925.43 2166.51 1132.43 2114.2C1132.43 2114.2 1478.22 2063.47 1538.11 2119.23C1538.11 2119.23 1602.78 2145.61 1589.79 2184.7C1589.79 2184.7 1523.37 2245.65 1501.18 2174.99C1501.18 2174.99 1473.43 2083.8 1864.06 2069.9C1864.06 2069.9 2193.51 2044.76 2395.77 2125.92C2598.03 2207.08 2766.55 2389.97 2765.26 2585.36C2763.97 2780.75 2534.94 3068.9 2354.4 3104.07C2354.4 3104.07 1701.6 3444.73 1149.06 3084.25C1149.06 3084.25 1089.83 2916.21 1102.75 2890.37C1102.75 2890.37 1458 2707.9 1551.66 2701.44C1551.66 2701.44 1278.76 2896.83 1168.96 2945.27L1235.17 2993.71L1291.69 3037.31C1291.69 3037.31 1336.9 3072.84 1359.51 3019.55C1359.51 3019.55 1458.01 2812.86 1614.64 2688.52C1614.64 2688.52 1634.63 2658.15 1569.92 2670.1C1505.21 2682.06 944.47 2814.02 951.69 2839.3C951.69 2839.3 959.28 2856.62 983.03 2863.88L1060.88 2902.8C1060.88 2902.8 1085.29 2905.44 1085.29 2952.28L1113.66 3063.11C1113.66 3063.11 1132.79 3111.93 1153.24 3050.58L1170.39 2985.93C1170.39 2985.93 1210.63 2996.49 1217.23 3028.81C1223.83 3061.14 1148.62 3124.53 1106.4 3126.81C1064.18 3129.09 1056.26 3080.99 960.6 3126.81C960.6 3126.81 841.07 3220.61 657.8 3157.73C657.8 3157.73 502.13 3118.78 426.04 3052.07C349.95 2985.36 461.48 2922.82 461.48 2922.82C461.48 2922.82 627.21 2848.82 655.35 2991.61C683.49 3134.41 452.1 3249.76 452.1 3249.76C452.1 3249.76 -15.4398 3335.59 119.23 3729.09C119.23 3729.09 107.11 3978.63 586.99 3910.88C586.99 3910.88 2257.89 3872.48 2605.22 4145.74C2605.22 4145.74 3100.25 4589.66 2337.62 4740.04C2337.62 4740.04 716.83 4867.29 463.77 4678.22C463.77 4678.22 6.67026 4496.03 395.63 4202.54C395.63 4202.54 838.22 3831.85 2469.84 4125.43C2469.84 4125.43 2784.49 4170.6 2852.99 4323.03C2921.49 4475.46 2656.35 4560.95 2413.48 4645.24C2170.61 4729.52 1357.9 4735.72 939.93 4683.22C939.93 4683.22 515.57 4654.89 434.13 4594.81C434.13 4594.81 172.03 4481.1 126.86 4828.32C126.86 4828.32 111.01 5071.71 527.2 5044.59C527.2 5044.59 613.84 4945.91 475.78 4968.01C475.78 4968.01 308.99 5093.49 549.32 5165.05C549.32 5165.05 724.26 5236.6 791.42 5356.77C858.57 5476.94 1113.04 5814.46 1505.34 5844.5C1505.34 5844.5 1632.57 5821.53 1595.46 5535.25C1595.46 5535.25 1573.34 5371.49 1685.56 5348.47C1685.56 5348.47 1676.93 5443.43 1533.05 5570.05C1533.05 5570.05 1430.89 5732.64 1510.03 5780.12C1510.03 5780.12 1596.36 5741.27 1525.86 5436.24C1525.86 5436.24 1463.99 5185.89 1351.76 5203.15C1351.76 5203.15 1318.2 5202.65 1324.36 5237.28C1324.36 5237.28 1318.97 5272.68 1373.61 5274.22C1373.61 5274.22 1521.36 5249.98 1519.05 5144.17C1519.05 5144.17 1525.21 5074.53 1462.87 5086.07C1462.87 5086.07 1438.24 5016.04 1382.07 5073.76C1382.07 5073.76 1345.9 5107.62 1372.07 5141.48C1372.07 5141.48 1402.08 5153.79 1395.93 5100.69C1395.93 5100.69 1389.2 5022.56 1285.22 5052.39C1285.22 5052.39 1242.03 5071.45 1258.19 5112.23C1258.19 5112.23 1198.94 5127.62 1214.33 5171.48C1214.33 5171.48 1217.38 5214.53 1270.51 5222.27C1270.51 5222.27 1286.51 5225.66 1297.61 5223.64C1297.61 5223.64 1327.88 5213.55 1299.12 5198.41C1299.12 5198.41 1220.41 5196.39 1217.89 5265.52C1217.89 5265.52 1210.83 5312.44 1275.41 5316.99C1275.41 5316.99 1274.91 5386.62 1350.09 5363.41C1350.09 5363.41 1407.11 5348.78 1406.6 5309.42C1406.6 5309.42 1410.13 5274.1 1372.29 5300.84C1372.29 5300.84 1347.06 5356.34 1403.07 5387.62C1403.07 5387.62 1470.18 5395.19 1474.21 5342.71C1474.21 5342.71 1547.88 5354.31 1543.84 5280.65C1543.84 5280.65 1539.3 5227.17 1501.46 5228.68" stroke="white" stroke-width="12.23" />
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0_57_20">
<rect width="2870.09" height="5850.64" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>

let path = document.querySelector('path')
    let pathLength = path.getTotalLength()
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      // What % down is it?
      var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
      // Lenght to offset the dashes
      var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
      // Draw in reverse
      path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
    })
```

```
.linecont {
 position: fixed;
 top: 60px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 }
```

Check the link for the code

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but it is much improved just by making changes to your CSS.

Each of your text blocks has a fixed pixel height, so there is some fixed size of the svg which will make things line up correctly.  I eyeballed it to be roughly:

```
svg {
  width: 1000px;
  height: auto;
}
```

You want the top of the svg to scroll offscreen with the content so you want `position: absolute` rather than `position: fixed` on `.linecont`.  I also removed the `height: 100%` here because it was not working properly.

```
.linecont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

We want the svg to scroll behind the header. So the header needs to have a `background-color` and it needs to have a `z-index` which places it above the svg.

```
nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #14032e;
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Your container height of `3000px` is taller than the height of the svg so the drawing doesn't end correctly.  You could change the way that you are computing the percentage, but it's easier to change the container height.  This is approximate, but it works well with:

```
.container {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```js
 let path = document.querySelector('path')
    let pathLength = path.getTotalLength()
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;

let svg = document.querySelector('svg');
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      // What % down is it?
      var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
      // Lenght to offset the dashes
      var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
      // Draw in reverse
      path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
    })
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "gosha sans";
}


body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #14032e;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.container {
  height: 2000px;
}
.content {
  width: 94%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.domanda2 {
  margin-top: 400px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.domanda3 {
  margin-top: 600px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.linecont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

svg {
  height: auto;
  width: 1000px;
}

.logo {
  line-height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  margin: 16px 100px;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  line-height: 60px;
  background-color: #14032e;
  z-index: 99;
}

nav ul {
  line-height: 60px;
  list-style: none;
  background: #14032e;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0;
  padding-right: 40px;
  transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
  background: #14032e;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 16px 40px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: gosha sans;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-icon {
  line-height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #14032e;
  text-align: right;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 15px 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 786px) {
  .logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }

  nav ul {
    max-height: 0px;
    background: #160433;
    opacity: 0.9;
  }

  nav.black ul {
    background-color: #000;
    color: white;
  }

  .showing {
    max-height: 50em;
    height: 500px;
  }

  nav ul li {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
  }

  
}
```

```html
<body>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="wrapper">
      <header>

        <nav>

          <div class="menu-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
          </div>

          <div class="logo"> <img src="faviconirene.png">

          </div>

          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">works</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
              <li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div class="container">

        <div class="content">
          <div class="linecont">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 2871 5851" fill="none" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax meet">
              <path d="M6.13024 0.179993C6.13024 0.179993 -5.93976 407.65 703.97 271.94C1413.87 136.23 2393.8 289.96 2554.29 374.76C2714.78 459.56 3224.73 1026.17 2375.85 1377.68C2375.85 1377.68 1684.78 1415.68 1548.28 1347.43C1548.28 1347.43 1428.6 1265.58 1525.95 1194.64C1525.95 1194.64 1558.95 1184.74 1589.47 1195.46C1619.99 1206.18 1611.44 1277.93 1585.35 1315.08C1559.25 1352.23 1448.8 1561.78 1448.8 1561.78L1421.52 1618.04C1421.52 1618.04 1450.94 1681.08 1466.07 1618.04C1466.07 1618.04 1377.04 1325.34 1258.06 1299.74C1258.06 1299.74 1206.16 1271.24 1126.9 1308.79C1126.9 1308.79 358.16 1882.7 232.06 1834.43C232.06 1834.43 123.27 1828.78 133.5 1730.38C143.73 1631.98 349.55 1673.12 313.92 1753.44C313.92 1753.44 317.75 1840.81 279.47 1901.13C279.47 1901.13 257.35 2043.32 496.97 2076.64C736.59 2109.96 925.43 2166.51 1132.43 2114.2C1132.43 2114.2 1478.22 2063.47 1538.11 2119.23C1538.11 2119.23 1602.78 2145.61 1589.79 2184.7C1589.79 2184.7 1523.37 2245.65 1501.18 2174.99C1501.18 2174.99 1473.43 2083.8 1864.06 2069.9C1864.06 2069.9 2193.51 2044.76 2395.77 2125.92C2598.03 2207.08 2766.55 2389.97 2765.26 2585.36C2763.97 2780.75 2534.94 3068.9 2354.4 3104.07C2354.4 3104.07 1701.6 3444.73 1149.06 3084.25C1149.06 3084.25 1089.83 2916.21 1102.75 2890.37C1102.75 2890.37 1458 2707.9 1551.66 2701.44C1551.66 2701.44 1278.76 2896.83 1168.96 2945.27L1235.17 2993.71L1291.69 3037.31C1291.69 3037.31 1336.9 3072.84 1359.51 3019.55C1359.51 3019.55 1458.01 2812.86 1614.64 2688.52C1614.64 2688.52 1634.63 2658.15 1569.92 2670.1C1505.21 2682.06 944.47 2814.02 951.69 2839.3C951.69 2839.3 959.28 2856.62 983.03 2863.88L1060.88 2902.8C1060.88 2902.8 1085.29 2905.44 1085.29 2952.28L1113.66 3063.11C1113.66 3063.11 1132.79 3111.93 1153.24 3050.58L1170.39 2985.93C1170.39 2985.93 1210.63 2996.49 1217.23 3028.81C1223.83 3061.14 1148.62 3124.53 1106.4 3126.81C1064.18 3129.09 1056.26 3080.99 960.6 3126.81C960.6 3126.81 841.07 3220.61 657.8 3157.73C657.8 3157.73 502.13 3118.78 426.04 3052.07C349.95 2985.36 461.48 2922.82 461.48 2922.82C461.48 2922.82 627.21 2848.82 655.35 2991.61C683.49 3134.41 452.1 3249.76 452.1 3249.76C452.1 3249.76 -15.4398 3335.59 119.23 3729.09C119.23 3729.09 107.11 3978.63 586.99 3910.88C586.99 3910.88 2257.89 3872.48 2605.22 4145.74C2605.22 4145.74 3100.25 4589.66 2337.62 4740.04C2337.62 4740.04 716.83 4867.29 463.77 4678.22C463.77 4678.22 6.67026 4496.03 395.63 4202.54C395.63 4202.54 838.22 3831.85 2469.84 4125.43C2469.84 4125.43 2784.49 4170.6 2852.99 4323.03C2921.49 4475.46 2656.35 4560.95 2413.48 4645.24C2170.61 4729.52 1357.9 4735.72 939.93 4683.22C939.93 4683.22 515.57 4654.89 434.13 4594.81C434.13 4594.81 172.03 4481.1 126.86 4828.32C126.86 4828.32 111.01 5071.71 527.2 5044.59C527.2 5044.59 613.84 4945.91 475.78 4968.01C475.78 4968.01 308.99 5093.49 549.32 5165.05C549.32 5165.05 724.26 5236.6 791.42 5356.77C858.57 5476.94 1113.04 5814.46 1505.34 5844.5C1505.34 5844.5 1632.57 5821.53 1595.46 5535.25C1595.46 5535.25 1573.34 5371.49 1685.56 5348.47C1685.56 5348.47 1676.93 5443.43 1533.05 5570.05C1533.05 5570.05 1430.89 5732.64 1510.03 5780.12C1510.03 5780.12 1596.36 5741.27 1525.86 5436.24C1525.86 5436.24 1463.99 5185.89 1351.76 5203.15C1351.76 5203.15 1318.2 5202.65 1324.36 5237.28C1324.36 5237.28 1318.97 5272.68 1373.61 5274.22C1373.61 5274.22 1521.36 5249.98 1519.05 5144.17C1519.05 5144.17 1525.21 5074.53 1462.87 5086.07C1462.87 5086.07 1438.24 5016.04 1382.07 5073.76C1382.07 5073.76 1345.9 5107.62 1372.07 5141.48C1372.07 5141.48 1402.08 5153.79 1395.93 5100.69C1395.93 5100.69 1389.2 5022.56 1285.22 5052.39C1285.22 5052.39 1242.03 5071.45 1258.19 5112.23C1258.19 5112.23 1198.94 5127.62 1214.33 5171.48C1214.33 5171.48 1217.38 5214.53 1270.51 5222.27C1270.51 5222.27 1286.51 5225.66 1297.61 5223.64C1297.61 5223.64 1327.88 5213.55 1299.12 5198.41C1299.12 5198.41 1220.41 5196.39 1217.89 5265.52C1217.89 5265.52 1210.83 5312.44 1275.41 5316.99C1275.41 5316.99 1274.91 5386.62 1350.09 5363.41C1350.09 5363.41 1407.11 5348.78 1406.6 5309.42C1406.6 5309.42 1410.13 5274.1 1372.29 5300.84C1372.29 5300.84 1347.06 5356.34 1403.07 5387.62C1403.07 5387.62 1470.18 5395.19 1474.21 5342.71C1474.21 5342.71 1547.88 5354.31 1543.84 5280.65C1543.84 5280.65 1539.3 5227.17 1501.46 5228.68" stroke="white" stroke-width="12.23" />
</g>
<defs>
<clipPath id="clip0_57_20">
<rect width="2870.09" height="5850.64" fill="white"/>
</clipPath>
</defs>
</svg>


          </div>
          <div class="domanda1">
            are you ready to tell your story?
          </div>

          <div class="domanda2">
            are you ready to fly?
          </div>

          <div class="domanda3">
            are you ready to purpling around?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
        $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
      });
    });
    // Scrolling Effect
    $(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if ($(window).scrollTop()) {
        $('nav').addClass('black');
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('black');
      }
    })
    
    
   
  </script>

</body>
```